# Firestore paginate documents for quiz app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a quiz app and I am struggling about data structure in firebase.

Actually, I have two collections:

- Questions collection, containing one document foreach question [image]
- Users Answers collection, containing one document foreach user. Inside user's document, there is one map per answered question where I store if question has been answered and if question has been right answered. [image]

So, where is the problem ? For my app, I need two things:

- Fetch list of a specific user answers. Actually there is no problem because I can query users answers collection for a specific user and retrieve all his answers within a single document.
- Fetch list of a questions never answered by user. This is a quiz app, so it is mandatory to show questions never answered by user to progress in the game.

The current (not best) solution is this : when the user launch the app, I request all questions, get his answers and then I can know which question I should show to user and the ones I shouldn't. The problem of this solution is that I have to query all the questions documents so it represents a large number of reads (and firebase bill by number of reads ).
I would like to paginate the number of questions to show to user (so questions never answered) to avoid extra-billing but I can't figure how to request them.
I tried to use not-in clause but it is limited to 10 items and I have a lot more than 10 questions.

I would like to know if you have any ideas to bypass this problem. Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: In users answers collection, does each user contain only answered questions?

Comment: @development-ninja Yes users answers collection contain only answered questions. I through about insert all questions but it means a lot more storage, a lot more writings and you need to reads all the question documents...

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't support using the results of a query to exclude documents from another query.  There are no SQL-like joins that query across documents in multiple collections.

If the provided inequality filter (10 items max) isn't sufficient for your use case, I'm afraid you're stuck with the solution you have now by filtering the results in the client app.

Some developers might choose to duplicate data into a SQL database to make these kinds of queries possible, but you'll have to decide for yourself if that's worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Doug Stevenson. This is what I feared. I will wait few days to see if someone has a better solution, if it's not the case, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider this, I am wondering this could make your idea work.
This will only work when the users you know are constant.
Every questions docs need to have this property: `not_answered_by`
And set all users' ids list inside this property initially for all questions.
Once a user answered against one question then update certain question doc to remove that user id from `not_answered_by` So like this below, I remove user who has id:`ccccc` inside `not_answered_by` list from question :`PXxzLaZp4kDSzewo7kht` when user answered on that question.
[image]

Then you can run this query `.where("not_answered_by", "array-contains", user_id)` against questions collection to get all questions not answered by selected user.
If you have this structure of questions collection, then the powerful advantage is that you don't have to query double to get questions not answered by user, which does cost time and money. The remove action from `not_answered_by` doesn't affect speed low because you know which user id to be removed from which question id.
One tip: if you dont want to set not_answered_by to have all users' id list initially then just have another property: `is_answer_started` to set `false` for all questions. And whenever question is started to be answered then set `not_answered_by` to have all users' list.
`not_answered_by` is array of strings and it doesn't affect to your cost of firebase, important fact on your side is getting result in cheap and fast right?

Important to note: this is case of users' id list are constant, this doesn't work if users collection is dynamic which means user is added dynamically so please think this is a tricky method but I think it is best approach for now.  PS: Firebase query doesn't support `array_not_contains` which I was about to find and use it. We can approach this in javascript via array includes function you know. :)
Vice versa, you can have `answerd_by` property inside question doc to get answered questions list against user.

Comment: Hello @development-ninja it's good approach and thank you for sharing it. Unfortunately and as you said, it can't work if users list is dynamic but this is my case.
Moreover it can make a problem if you have too many users (and I hope it will be my case haha) because arrays in document has a limit.